# What is the effect of the dot (.) in the Java classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, javac, scjp

This is an example question from "SCJP mock exam":

> Given the default classpath:
>
> /foo
>
> And this directory structure:
>
> ```
> foo
>   |
>  test
>     |
>    xcom
>      |--A.class
>      |--B.java
> ```
>
> And these two files:
>
> ```
> package xcom;
> public class A { }
> package xcom;
> public class B extends A { }
> ```
>
> Which allows B.java to compile? (Choose all that apply.)
>
> A. Set the current directory to `xcom` then invoke
>
> ```
> javac B.java
> ```
>
> B. Set the current directory to `xcom` then invoke
>
> ```
> javac -classpath . B.java
> ```
>
> C. Set the current directory to test then invoke
>
> ```
> javac -classpath . xcom/B.java
> ```
>
> D. Set the current directory to test then invoke
>
> ```
> javac -classpath xcom B.java
> ```
>
> E. Set the current directory to test then invoke
>
> ```
> javac -classpath xcom:. B.java
> ```

The answer is C, I don't understand the use of the operator `.` there. Please explain.

The book says:

> In order for `B.java` to compile, the compiler first needs to be able to find `B.java`.
>   Once it's found `B.java`, it needs to find `A.class`. **Because `A.class` is in the
>   `xcom` package the compiler won't find `A.class`** if it's invoked from the `xcom` directory.
>   Remember that the `-classpath` isn't looking for `B.java`, it's looking for whatever classes
>   `B.java` needs (in this case `A.class`).

I don't get this, if both files are on the same package, why wouldn't the compiler find A?

Answer (score 5):

the dot means 'the current directory'.
If you call javac from within `xcom`, then it will look for `A.class` in `xcom/xcom/A.class`, and won't find it.

Comment: You mean if I call it without the dot?

Comment: no. the dot identifies that xcom/A.class is on the classpath. But if you call javac from within xcom, it will search for A in current_dir/xcom/A.class, and since current_dir IS xcom, it will search in xcom/xcom/A.class. And it is not there.

Answer (score 3):

> In order for `B.java` to compile, the compiler first needs to be able to find `B.java`.

This is why D. and E. are wrong.

> Once it's found `B.java`, it needs to find `A.class`. Because A.class is in the `xcom` package the compiler won't find `A.class` if it's invoked from the `xcom` directory. (...)

You missed the important part here which is ***if it's invoked from the `xcom` directory***. `A.class` is in the `xcom` package so it is expected to be found in `xcom/A.class` (relatively to where you run javac).

This is why A. and B. are wrong. 
And this leave C. as the right answer.

Comment: Actually, E would work too, but it is not the "right way" to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operator `.`, the `.` means current directory. Since class `A` is in the `xcom` package and since, with `javac`, the directory hierarchy mirrors the package hierarchy, you need to have a directory in the class path from which the file `xcom/A.class` can be found. In your case, that is the `test` directory, so when you invoke `javac` in that directory, giving the current directory in the class path, `javac` will find the class `xcom.A` from the `xcom` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got confused too while reading your quotation of the book.

Anyway the compiler will look for the `A.class` and because it is in the same package as `B.java`, it will look for `xcom/A.class`. That means you have to tell the compiler where to find your packages and you do this with `-classpath`.

In your example your packages (it could be more than one) are in `test` and this what your a telling the compiler with the dot since you are in test.

In short, the compiler looks for class by prefixing their package name as directory.