# How this option is valid? -classpath confusion

Tags: java, classpath

I am reading java certification book and here is the question from the book. Please have a
look at the following directory structure shown in picture.

[image: Directory Structure]

Here is the source code for A.class and B.java

```
package xcom;
public class A{}

package xcom;
public class B extends A{}
```

Which allows B.java to compile.

1. Set the current directory to test then invoke
   javac -classpath . xcom/B.java
2. Set the current directory to test then invoke
   javac -classpath xcom B.java
3. Set the current directory to test and then invoke
   javac -classpath xcom:. B.java

It says option 1 is correct and its actually compiling as well. My point is that basically in order for B.java to compile, it needs to find A.class. We are in directory test and when we say -classpath ., it searches for files in current directory. But A.class is not present in current directory. Can someone explain this concept to me?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period is telling it to search the current folder for the following path in this instance. Since you are setting the current directory to test and invoking 
`-classpath . xcom/B.java`
it is like saying 
`search this folder(the test folder) for xcom/B.java)`

There are some similar questions such as this one: [What is the effect of the dot (.) in the Java classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897132/what-is-the-effect-of-the-dot-in-the-java-classpath?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks so much double. I am slowly grasping the concepts seems like. Thankyou.